# Can I retrieve data from the server and store it in core data?

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I'm a newbie and working on a pull to refresh app.

I have watched the tutorial of using Sqlite3 in ios6 to build data driven app. When the user pull to refresh the app will load the data from the server and then store it locally and display it on the tableView and the user can also edit and save back to the server.

Can this be done using core data not Sqlite3? because I find it really difficult to make Objective-C interface that will interact with C language (the Sqlite3).

Or are there any better solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Core Data for this task. You can use Mogenerator with Core data to create a core data model for you. Then use Magical Records to easy saving and fetching of core data. These two libraries make Core Data super simple and nice. As for pulling info from the server, you'll have to model the data recieved to the models created by Mogenerator and then save them into core data. Again with taking data from core data and pushing it to a server, depending on what you're using to communicate with the server, you'll need to create a dictionary to mimic the JSON you'll need to send to the server and then push it off. As far as I know theres nothing to directly communicate the info from Core Data directly to the server. Anyway you'll probably have to play around with this concept, but my recommendation is definitely use Mogenerator to get the core data NSManagedObjects and then MagicalRecord for super easy saving and fetching.